# Termination checking failed to prove ∃-even′ : ∀ {n : ℕ} → ∃[ m ] ( 2 * m ≡ n) → even n

Tags: agda, termination, plfa

The PLFA exercise: what if we write the arithmetic more "naturally" in Quantifiers chapter (https://plfa.github.io/Quantifiers/) ?

```
∃-even′ : ∀ {n : ℕ} → ∃[ m ] (    2 * m ≡ n) → even n
∃-odd′  : ∀ {n : ℕ} → ∃[ m ] (2 * m + 1 ≡ n) →  odd n
```

I have make the type right. But have got **Termination checking failed for the following functions:**

```
dbl≡2* : ∀ n → n + n ≡ 2 * n
dbl≡2* n = cong (n +_) (sym (+-identityʳ n))

+-suc1 : ∀ (m : ℕ) → m + 1 ≡ suc m
+-suc1 m =
  begin
    m + 1
    ≡⟨⟩
    m + (suc zero)
    ≡⟨ +-suc m zero ⟩
    suc (m + zero)
    ≡⟨ cong suc (+-identityʳ m) ⟩
    suc m
    ∎ 

help1 : ∀ m → 2 * m + 1 ≡ suc (m + m)
help1 m =
  begin
    2 * m + 1
    ≡⟨  sym ( cong (_+ 1) (dbl≡2* m) ) ⟩
    m + m + 1  -- must use every rule
    ≡⟨ +-assoc m m 1 ⟩
    m + (m + 1)
    ≡⟨ cong (m +_) (+-suc1 m) ⟩
    m + suc m
    ≡⟨ +-suc m m ⟩
    suc (m + m)
    ∎

∃-even′ ⟨ zero , refl ⟩ = even-zero
∃-even′ ⟨ suc m , refl ⟩ rewrite +-identityʳ m
                | +-suc m m
                = even-suc (∃-odd′ ⟨ (m) ,  help1 m ⟩)

∃-odd′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩ rewrite +-suc (2 * m) 0
                | +-identityʳ m
                | +-identityʳ (m + m)
                | dbl≡2* m
                = odd-suc (∃-even′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩)
```

For the normal version, the same mutually-recursive define can work fine.

```
∃-even : ∀ {n : ℕ} → ∃[ m ] (    m * 2 ≡ n) → even n
∃-odd  : ∀ {n : ℕ} → ∃[ m ] (1 + m * 2 ≡ n) →  odd n

∃-even ⟨ zero , refl ⟩ = even-zero
∃-even ⟨ suc x , refl ⟩ = even-suc (∃-odd ⟨ x , refl ⟩)
∃-odd ⟨ x , refl ⟩ = odd-suc (∃-even ⟨ x , refl ⟩)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
∃-even′ ⟨ zero , refl ⟩ = even-zero
∃-even′ ⟨ suc m , refl ⟩ rewrite +-identityʳ m
                | +-suc m m
                = even-suc (∃-odd′ ⟨ m ,  help1 m ⟩)

∃-odd′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩ rewrite +-suc (2 * m) 0
                | +-identityʳ m
                | +-identityʳ (m + m)
                | dbl≡2* m
                = odd-suc (∃-even′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩)
```

Your recursive calls are:

- `∃-even′ ⟨ suc m , refl ⟩` -> `∃-odd′ ⟨ m ,  help1 m ⟩`
- `∃-odd′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩` -> `∃-even′ ⟨ m , refl ⟩`

In the first one, `suc m` -> `m` decreases, but `refl` -> `help1 m` (on its surface) increases. If you passed `refl` as the second argument to `∃-odd′`, then the termination checker would accept it, since it means the second argument stays the same, while the first one strictly monotonically decreases over a complete chain of two calls.

So how can we change that first recursive call to `∃-odd′ ⟨ m ,  refl ⟩`? By rewriting by `sym (help1 m)`:

```
∃-even′ ( suc m , refl ) rewrite +-identityʳ m
                | +-suc m m
                | sym (help1 m)
                = even-suc (∃-odd′ (m ,  refl))
```

This code is then accepted by the termination checker.

Comment: Change to your suggestion and still have Termination checking failed. My agda version is  2.6.1.2

Comment: Here's the full code with all imports (doesn't use anything PLFA-specific): https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/ffc02d72b0fd6ac06a1050c255998a45 Tested on Agda version 2.6.2-d713902-dirty

Comment: You are right. I will continue check why my PLFA-version still failed. It seem PLFA redefine some idea like : Isomorphism and Quantifiers

Comment: Can't check right now, just a wild guess, but could it be that their Sigma type definition does not have eta, and could that be causing this?